# Cant run project on lower api version it runs on lollipop and marshmallow

Tags: android, api

I have downloaded android studio 2.2.1 but I can't run my project on lower API version it runs on lollipop and marshmallow. My module .gradle content is as follows:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion '24.0.3'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.admin.autoworld"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2',        {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:+'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
compile 'fr.avianey.com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1.1@aar'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

this is the log cat ...its shows some error in splash screen

```
    FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.admin.autoworld, PID: 4574
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.admin.autoworld/com.example.admin.autoworld.SplashScreen}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #27: Error inflating class android.widget.ImageView
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2441)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2500)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:171)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1309)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5679)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
               Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #27: Error inflating class android.widget.ImageView
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:626)
                  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:675)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:700)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
                  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:350)
                  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2059)
                  at com.example.admin.autoworld.SplashScreen.onCreate(SplashScreen.java:18)
```

here is the xml file for splash screen

Comment: Your question is unclear. What exactly are you trying to do, and what is the problem you are encountering? Also, please format the `build.gradle` file contents properly in your question - it's too difficult to read otherwise.

Comment: why you can't run on lower APIs? Have you tried to run? What is the result?

Comment: I am new to android..i have build app but i am unable to run in the lower version of phones ..

Comment: @Vlad Matvienko:yes i have tested it on marshmallo and lolipop it works fine but when i test it on android version 4.4.4 its gives error unfortunately stop

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.admin.autoworld, PID: 2015
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.admin.autoworld/com.example.admin.autoworld.SplashScreen}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.widget.ImageView
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2

Comment: @Deepak it's not an issue of api levels. kindly add full exception text in your question for better understanding of issue.

Comment: there is some problem with your `ImageView` in `SplashScreen`. Show the XML

Comment: try to clean and rebuild

Comment: or else maybe you used a material design? use support libraries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried a lot and finaly found the answer ....as i was using material design its not supported to lover api...i have removed custom toolbar and recreated the project from start

Answer (score 0):

Since your question is unclear, I'll just try to give you an answer.

Application compatibility may occur when you built your app from lollipop or marshmallow and tried to compile in lower version without noticing you've wrote it in material design.

You better try to change your design issues if you want to run it on kitkat or lower

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html

I've also encountered it in kitkat and need to change design to appcompatactivity (in xamarin C#) to support the material designs i've used :)

NOTE:: you don't need to change it literally, just change the coding to support material design on lower version. You can use material design on lower version but you have to support it

Comment: @jace-can u share some example

Comment: Your error is InflateException which is sometimes caused by missing something in your code or wrong support or not supporting at all. It's hard to give an example or even a direct answer without xml and code to create comparison. :)